# Using RPI2 model B to read multiple IMU units

Tags: sensor, i2c, matlab

I have 3 IMU units "mpu-6050" and I want to read all three in real time. The IMU's communication protocol is I2C. As I noticed the model b has two I2C options : I2C0, I2C1.

1. Does RPI2 can read multiple imu's and display them in a graphics design with matlab for example ?
2. A Multiplexer can be a solution for 3 imu's with 2 ports of I2C?

That is my first project.

HS

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd I²C is reserved (although it can be used if necessary).
I²C can support multiple devices (with different addresses).

You need to supply more details of the devices and if they support multiple addresses.

Comment: Just a note to say that i2c-0 is not available on the Pi3 (reserved for system use).  This is not a problem for the Pi2.

Comment: Thank you guys for answers, Milliways the I2C I known to be able to work with multiple devices. The devices should support multiple addresses. Can RPI 2 handle 3 threads at the same time(for each imu) with fourth thread that reacts to imu's output?

Comment: @Hadar.S You can write multi threaded code, but that seems an unnecessary complication and hardly appropriate for a slow interface like I²C and way off topic for your original question.